# Return boolean to function calling it - Javascript/Polymer

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

I have a top function calling multiple functions, each with a Boolean within. I'm wanting to use the returned Boolean values within the top function to do something else there. Is this at all possible?

**Example:**

*please don't get hung up on what the functions actually work out, but please only focus on if/how they can pass their Boolean natures back to the topFunct*

```
topFunct : function() {
    variable1 = this.$......;
    variable2 = this.$......;
    variable3 = this.$......;

    this.funct1();
    this.funct2();

    if(funct1() && funct2()) {
       //DO SOMETHING ELSE
    }
},

funct1 : function() {
    if(variable1 == variable2) {
        return true;
    } else return false;
},

funct2 : function() {
    if(variable2 == variable3) {
        return true;
    } else return false;
},
```

Comment: Are `variable1` etc. supposed to be globally scoped…? And what's wrong with `var res1 = funct1()`?

Comment: Thank you @deceze!
And yes, the variables were made intentionally global, because otherwise I couldn't pass their values to the functions.... Do you have any ideas if I can have them non-global and still pass them down?

Comment: --- FIXED --- see my answer for how I sorted it (with a colleague's help!)

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is in TopFunct: `return this.funct1() && this.funct2();`

Comment: Hey Diego, this didn't work for me. I was still having the issue of debugger saying the functions not being defined etc. However, @deceze gave an answer just below my question that seems to have done the trick. Thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 0):

@deceze posted an answer for me that worked out great.

TopFunct now appears as such:

```
topFunct : function() {
    variable1 = this.$......;
    variable2 = this.$......;
    variable3 = this.$......;

    var result1 = this.funct1();
    var result2 = this.funct2();

    if(result1 && result2) {
       //DO SOMETHING ELSE
    }
},
```

Globally scoping variables is silly, so a fix can be seen as:

```
 topFunct : function() {
    var params = {};

    params.variable1 = this.$......;
    params.variable2 = this.$......;
    params.variable3 = this.$......;

    var result1 = this.funct1(params);
    var result2 = this.funct2(params);

    if(result1 && result2) {
       //DO SOMETHING ELSE
    }
},

funct1 : function(params) {
    //  to use the params within here, must access them via their definitions in TopFunct.
    //  params.variable1
    //  params.variable2
    //  etc
}
```